# mittsu vs san - what's the difference and what are these two forms called?

Tags: word-choice, counters, numbers

I am trying to learn the numbers and I see there are two different translations for the number 3 (and other numbers). When should I use one and when should I use the other? Is there a name for the type of number that "san" is and the type of number that "mittsu" is?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_numerals

Comment: It's complicated. The numbers change depending on what you are counting. Most of the time you need a special counter word that goes with the number. Some of them change the way the number is written. I suggest you research "Japanese counters"  on the internet and ask here again if you have a more specific question.

Answer (score 5):

There are mainly two types of numbers used in Japanese:

- native Japanese numbers (和語数詞 *wago sūshi*)

  > 1 ひと *hito*, 　2 ふた *futa*, 　3 み *mi*, 　4 よ *yo*, 　5 いつ *itsu*, 　6 む *mu*, 　7 なな *nana*, 　8 や *ya*, 　9 ここの *kokono*, 　10 と *to*, 　...
- Chinese-derived numbers (漢語数詞 *kango sūshi*)

  > 1 いち *ichi*, 　2 に *ni*, 　3 さん *san*, 　4 し *shi*, 　5 ご *go*, 　6 ろく *roku*, 　7 しち *shichi*, 　8 はち *hachi*, 　9 きゅう *kyū*, 　10 じゅう *jū*, 　...

(Some counters may also take English-derived numbers (英語数詞 *eigo sūshi*) ワン *wan* "one", ツー *tsū* "two", スリー *surī* "three" in low numbers.)

**Caveat**. Depending on the counter word coming after it, these numbers may slightly change.

---

#### *mittsu*

The native みっつ *mittsu* is of the form [number] + [counter word], where the number is the native Japanese み *mi* that goes with the counter word ～つ (a generic counter for objects) and

> み + ～つ → み**っ**つ. (See the above caveat.)

#### *san*

さん *san* is of the form [number], where the number belongs to the Chinese-derived counting system. It cannot be used to count anything (items, people, ...) by itself.

However, for counting by itself (e.g. during exercise, hide-and-seek, etc.) the Chinese-derived numbers are used (sometimes しち is replaced by なな).

<sub>During counting, these are often *pronounced* rhythmically</sub>

> <sup>イチ【HL】、　ニー【HL】、　サン【HL】、　シー【HL】、　ゴー【HL】、　ロク【HL】、　シチ【HL】、　ハチ【HL】、　キュウ【HHL】、　ジュウ【HHL】</sup>

<sup>even though they are always *written* as above.</sup>