# Small あ after は?

Tags: particle-は, culture, spoken-language

I’m trying to read a book but I came across a sentence where there are small あs after はs and I’m not sure why. Do you know why that is and what it means?

> その時【とき】、子供【こども】たちの声【こえ】が聞こえました【きこえました】。
>   「鬼【おに】**はぁ**外【そと】、福【ふく】**はぁ**内【うち】。」
>   おじいさんは言いました【いいました】。
>   「あっ、そうか。今日【きょう】は節分【せつぶん】か。」

[image: 鬼はぁ外、福はぁ内]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The phrase 「鬼【おに】は外【そと】、福【ふく】は内【うち】」 is said during the 豆まき *mamemaki* performed as part of [節分](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%AF%80%E5%88%86) [*Setsubun*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setsubun).

It is often recited *rhythmically*

> [●]{オ}[●]{ニ}[●]{ワ}[●]{ー}[●]{ソ}[●]{ト}○○[●]{フ}[●]{ク}[●]{ワ}[●]{ー}[●]{ウ}[●]{チ}○○

Just writing 「鬼は外、福は内」 just looks/reads very ordinary, so here the small ぁ is added to convey the (rhythmical) sound of the children singing/reciting the phrase.

(Rhythm can also change the pronunciation of the numbers when [counting](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/42552/1628), for example during hide-and-seek.)

Comment: I'm not sure OP would have been so confused if he'd ever actually *heard* this phrase aloud.

Comment: Correct. If I ever hear ghost children singing during a bean throwing festival, I'll make sure to remember this!